# Xcode 4.2 with iOS SDK 6.0, error compiling .xcdatamodeld file

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, xcdatamodel

I copied iOS 6 SDK files from xcode 4.5 (dmg) to my computer with snow leopard with xcode 4.2 using this:

sudo cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
sudo cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
sudo cp -R /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/6.0\ (10A403) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
sudo rm -f /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/Latest
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
sudo ln -s ./6.0\ (10A403) ./Latest

I opened my iPad project in xcode 4.2 an here shows an error that says:

"Uncategorized. Compilation failed for data model at path '/User/desarrollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/...app/...momd/...mom'"

The xcdatamodeld reference and file exists in project and folder.

Could you help me with this issue??

I think it is not a problem related with iOS 6 SDK because I've been trying clean and build project also with iOS 5.1 as target but it show the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your hardware keeping you from running Lion? If possible, upgrade to Lion and then Xcode 4.5.x. Your life will be easier. The newer Xcode is much better than 4.2.